# ¿Que hace el comando /bin/busybox --install –s?

Tags: línea-de-comandos

Me gustaría saber que realiza la invocación

```
/bin/busybox --install –s .
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

En general uno pide que las preguntas contengan un ejemplo de código, pero esta es más genérica y supongo no me quemarán en la hoguera por responder.

Si no aplicas `--install` o no lo compilas usando `make install`, llamarías a busybox como

```
 /ruta_de_busybox/busybox
```

O bien si se instaló en la carpeta de ejecutables (/`usr/bin, /usr/sbin, /bin` etc) directamente como

```
 busybox
```

Por ejemplo para encontrar los archivos modificados desde ayer

```
 busybox find . -type f -mtime -1
```

Y así lo mismo para replicar el comportamiento de awk, blkid, cat, lt, cut, diff, du, df, etc.

Si tú hicieras un symlink

```
 ln -s /usr/bin/busybox /usr/bin/find
```

Podrías llamar a `find` (que en realidad sigue siendo `busybox`) y éste entendería que quisiste hacer `busibox find`. O sea vas a tener el comando `find` con el mismo comportamiento de un linux normal.

Cuando haces `busybox --install -s`, éste hace los symlinks por ti para todos los comandos que provee.

La diferencia de usar `-s` es que crea links simbólicos y no hardlinks. La ventaja de los symlinks es que no tienen las mismas restricciones que los hardlinks, en los cuales, por ejemplo, no puedes referenciar elementos de otra partición, otro disco, o elementos montados por ejemplo via NFS.